# Remove command in loop

Tags: linux, rm

I wold like to know if I issue the command **rm -rf */????sample** to remove all the files like 0000sample  to 9999sample.  Is there any possibility that once deleting all the file the command still continues to run?

I think I'm loosing the data continuously. I only wanted it to run once. Looks like it is not allowing the files to build up again.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as unclear until such time that more information is added regarding the symptoms, any error messages, and what the workflow that you are using looks like (is there an application that is continuously writing to these files, for example?).

Answer (score 2):

No, it runs until completion and then it stops. There's no way it accidentally remains running. That would require additional commands.

One thing that could happen is that the app that is writing to those files continues to write to the deleted files. The app that writes to those files has been running since before the `rm`?

Comment: To check this, run `lsof | grep '....sample'` and look for files with a `(deleted)` marker.